AWS Cognito: Edit attribute verification
I'm able to send the email once the user updates its email on my app. This is the code that I'm using:
import { CustomMessageTriggerHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

const verifyEmailTemplate = (name: string, linkParameter: string): string => {
  const nameWrapper = name ? ` ${name}` : '';
  const body = `
    <h2>
      Please verify your email
    </h2>
    <p>
      Hi${nameWrapper}
    </p>
    <div>
        <a href="${linkParameter}">CLICK HERE TO VERIFY YOUR EMAIL</a>
    </div>
   `;
  return body;
};

export const handler: CustomMessageTriggerHandler = async (event) => {
  console.debug('event: ', event);
  try {
    const { ENVIRONMENT } = process.env;
    const email = ENVIRONMENT === 'local' ? null : event.request.userAttributes.email;
    const name = ENVIRONMENT === 'local' ? '' : event.request.userAttributes.name;
    const code = event.request.codeParameter;
    const linkParameter = event.request.linkParameter;
    
    if (
      event.triggerSource === 'CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute' &&
      event.request.userAttributes.email_verified !== 'true'
    ) {
      console.debug('CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute',); // I'm seeing this on the logs...
      event.response = {
        emailSubject: 'Your account updates needs to be verified', // I'm seeing this on the email title
        emailMessage: verifyEmailTemplate(name, linkParameter), // I'm not seeing this body email message.
        smsMessage: `test`,
      };
    }
    return event;
  } catch (error) {
  }
};

The things is that the result of this method: verifyEmailTemplate(name, linkParameter) has been replaced for some other template. Also is not sending the email verification link, is sending a verification code.
On Edit attribute verification and user account confirmation section in Sign-up experience tab I have this list:

Send SMS message, verify phone number
Send email message, verify email address
Send SMS message if phone number is available, otherwise send email message [THIS ONE IS ACTIVATED]

I can't understand what am I doing wrong, Even the template that is being sent is not in any of these list of templates:
Message templates:

Verification message.
Invitation message.
MFA Message

None of those templates are being use. The template that it's being send is:

Please verify your email Thanks for signing up, to complete your
registration please verify your e-mail address 473080

This is the event that I'm getting:
DEBUG   event:  {
  version: '1',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  userPoolId: 'us-east-1_d',
  userName: '3448e458',
  callerContext: {
    awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-js-3.670.0',
    clientId: '6cac2thnduoep1o9n8rjfhnifi'
  },
  triggerSource: 'CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute',
  request: {
    userAttributes: {
      sub: '3448e458',
      email_verified: 'false',
      'cognito:user_status': 'CONFIRMED',
      'custom:staged_email': 'noise@gmail.com',
      phone_number_verified: 'true',
      phone_number: '+14133248551',
      given_name: 'John',
      family_name: 'Doe',
      email: 'jdoe13@icloud.com',
    },
    codeParameter: '{####}',
    linkParameter: '{##Click Here##}',
    usernameParameter: null
  },
  response: { smsMessage: null, emailMessage: null, emailSubject: null }
}


Add a console.error(error.message) within the catch clause to check if you have any errors thrown at runtime. If there are logical errors thrown, then your lambda would not customize the response object and the default message would be sent out.

Non error @SalvinoD'sa I removed the error log from the code in order to make it shorter.

Does your code work with simple email messages?

It works @hoangdv
